# Class inside the jar not getting recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jboss, ejb

I am getting a class not found exception. Please check the screen shot. I have added the library in build path.

Thank you.

Screenshot removed

Kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Comment: screen shot requires 10 reputations. I tried

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you have is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError but not java.lang.ClassNotFoundException . So probably you are having multiple versions for the jar. My guess is jboss is including the jar from a module while you are including the jar in ear.

Comment: no, because if I remove the jar from my build path, immediately its showing error in all the corresponding classes. When I use eclipse hint, its asking me to include the jar file which is possible for me only from a physical location. For all the jars that are supplied by JBoss , eclipse  is not showing error, also in some cases if the jar is not recognized eclipse asks me to configure the build path . So it is proved that there is only one jar available for the project of this type.

Comment: I think you are confusing with eclipse and jboss classpath. Just because you added a jar in eclipse will not make it available in jboss also. Can you tell me how you are deploying your application in jboss

Comment: Eclipse - Right Click on project - Run as - Run in server.

Comment: I hope the jar will be available in the generated EAR

Comment: Go the deployments folder and check your ear. You can go to deployments by right Click the deployment(In server tab) and select the option to open in file explorer